# python immediately changes variables after closing gui

Tags: python, pygame

I have a simple TicTacToe game im trying to make but after i close the program and reopen it, it changes the value. why is this happening?

```py
import pygame
from sys import exit
from debug15 import debug15

pygame.init()
CROSIRCLE = 1


def layoutdraw():
    pygame.draw.line(screen, White, (233, 0), (233, 700), 7)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, White, (0, 233), (700, 233), 7)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, White, (467, 0), (467, 700), 7)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, White, (0, 467), (700, 467), 7)


def xoadder(x, y, determiner):
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and determiner == 1:
        if CROSIRCLE % 2 == 1:
            screen.blit(CROSS, (x, y))
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and determiner == 2:
        if CROSIRCLE % 2 == 0:
            screen.blit(CIRCLE, (x, y))


screenHI = 700
screenWID = 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWID, screenHI))
pygame.display.set_caption("TicTacToe")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen.fill((132, 132, 132))

# vars
White = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)

running = True
CROSIRCLE_CONTROLLER = 0
CROSS = pygame.image.load("CROSS.png")
CIRCLE = pygame.image.load("CIRCLE.png")
mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if mx <= 233 and my <= 233 and CROSIRCLE % 2 == 1:
            xoadder(0, 0, 1)
            CROSIRCLE = CROSIRCLE + 1
        if 233 <= mx and mx >= 466 and my <= 233 and CROSIRCLE % 2 == 0:
            xoadder(233, 0, 2)
    # layout
    layoutdraw()

    debug15(CROSIRCLE, 0, 0, True)
    debug15(CROSIRCLE % 2, 0, 50, True)
    debug15((mx, my), 0, 100, True)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

The CROSIRCLE value changed to two after i closed the gui. I have absolutely no idea why. there seems to be nothing wrong.

Comment: Which GUI? There is no GUI in your application.

Comment: You should add a `break` after `running = False` to immediately quit the while loop because the other if conditions might still trigger.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
import pygame
import sys, time

pygame.init()

WINSIZE = min(pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h)

WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500), pygame.RESIZABLE)

CROSS, CIRCLE = pygame.image.load("cross.png"), pygame.image.load("circle.png")

_CROSS, _CIRCLE = pygame.transform.scale(CROSS, (500 / 3, 500 / 3)), pygame.transform.scale(CIRCLE, (500 / 3, 500 / 3))
_CROSS.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255)); _CIRCLE.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))

field = [[2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2]]

move = 0

def draw_background(SURFACE, SIZE):
    SURFACE.fill((132, 132, 132))
    
    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, (255, 255, 255), (SIZE / 3, 0), (SIZE / 3, SIZE), 7)
    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, (255, 255, 255), (SIZE / 1.5, 0), (SIZE / 1.5, SIZE), 7)

    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, (255, 255, 255), (0, SIZE / 3), (SIZE, SIZE / 3), 7)
    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, (255, 255, 255), (0, SIZE / 1.5), (SIZE, SIZE / 1.5), 7)

def draw_grid(SURFACE, SIZE, ICONS, FIELD):
    for x, a in enumerate(FIELD):
        for y, i in enumerate(a):
            if i != 2:
                SURFACE.blit(ICONS[i], ICONS[i].get_rect(center=((x + 0.5) * SIZE / 3, (y + 0.5) * SIZE / 3)))

def check(FIELD):
    for a in range(2):
        if FIELD[0] == [a, a, a] or FIELD[1] == [a, a, a] or FIELD[2] == [a, a, a]:
            return a

        elif [FIELD[0][0], FIELD[1][0], FIELD[2][0]] == [a, a, a] or [FIELD[0][1], FIELD[1][1], FIELD[2][1]] == [a, a, a] or [FIELD[0][2], FIELD[1][2], FIELD[2][2]] == [a, a, a]:
            return a

        elif [FIELD[0][0], FIELD[1][1], FIELD[2][2]] == [a, a, a] or [FIELD[2][0], FIELD[1][1], FIELD[0][2]] == [a, a, a]:
            return a

def draw_win(SURFACE, SIZE, PLAYER):
    pygame.display.set_mode((SIZE, SIZE), pygame.NOFRAME)
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
    font2 = pygame.font.Font(None, SIZE - max(font.size("!!!_BLUE WON_!!!")[1], font.size("!!!_RED WON_!!!")[1]))
    
    if PLAYER:
        for a in range(3):
            SURFACE.fill((255, 255, 255))
            SURFACE.blit(font.render("!!!_BLUE WON_!!!", True, (0, 0, 255)), ((SIZE - font.size("!!!_BLUE WON_!!!")[0]) / 2, 0))
            SURFACE.blit(font2.render(str(3 - a), True, (132, 132, 132)), (((SIZE - font2.size(str(3 - a))[0]) / 2, (SIZE - font2.size(str(3 - a))[1]) / 2)))
            pygame.display.update()
            time.sleep(1)

        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    else:
        for a in range(3):
            SURFACE.fill((255, 255, 255))
            SURFACE.blit(font.render("!!!_RED WON_!!!", True, (255, 0, 0)), ((SIZE - font.size("!!!_RED WON_!!!")[0]) / 2, 0))
            SURFACE.blit(font2.render(str(3 - a), True, (132, 132, 132)), (((SIZE - font2.size(str(3 - a))[0]) / 2, (SIZE - font2.size(str(3 - a))[1]) / 2)))
            pygame.display.update()
            time.sleep(1)

        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    
draw_background(WINDOW, 500)
draw_grid(WINDOW, 500, [_CROSS, _CIRCLE], field)

pygame.display.update()

while True:
    size = pygame.display.get_window_size()[0]
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                x, y = event.pos[0], event.pos[1]
                x //= size // 3
                y //= size // 3

                if field[x][y] == 2:
                    field[x][y] = move
                    move = not move

                    draw_background(WINDOW, size)
                    draw_grid(WINDOW, size, [_CROSS, _CIRCLE], field)

                    c = check(field)
                    if c != None:
                         draw_win(WINDOW, size, c)

                    pygame.display.update()

        elif event.type == pygame.WINDOWRESIZED:
            size = min(max(event.x, event.y), WINSIZE)
            pygame.display.set_mode((size, size), pygame.RESIZABLE)

            _CROSS, _CIRCLE = pygame.transform.scale(CROSS, (size / 3, size / 3)), pygame.transform.scale(CIRCLE, (size / 3, size / 3))
            _CROSS.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255)); _CIRCLE.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))

            draw_background(WINDOW, size)
            draw_grid(WINDOW, size, [_CROSS, _CIRCLE], field)

            pygame.display.update()
```